# How to reuse common AngularFlexLayout properties

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-flex-layout

We are using the [angular-flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) to do sizing in our app.  There are several tags that we use in multiple places in our app.  For example, this block is used for all "top level" divs.

```
<div ...
     fxFlex="900px"
     fxFlex.lt-md="90%"
     ... >
```

I am trying to figure out how to change this so that if we want to refactor later there is only one place that we need to change.

Options I have considerred:

*Option #1 - Don't use fxFlex for this*

Maybe this is a usecase that doesn't work well with fxFlex.  I think I could do this:

```
<div ...
     class="mainWidthApp"
     ... >
```

Then I could write CSS using media queries to handle the multiple page widths.  Yuck.  Don't really want to do this.

*Option #2 - Use fxFlex and create a new directive*

This allows us to do something like this:

```
<div ...
     jakeAppWidth
     ... >
```

We can then define a directive to do something like this:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[jakeAppWidth]'
})
export class AppWidthDirective {

    constructor(element: ElementRef) {

        // Not sure how to do this yet, but do something like: 
        element.addSubDirective( fxFlex="900px" );
        element.addSubDirective( fxFlex.lt-md="90%" );

    }

}
```

Not sure if it is possible to have a directive that adds directives.  Still looking into this.

*Option #3 - Other...*

I think that this must be a fairly common problem.  Maybe there is an out of 
the box solution.

Thanks!